# chrome extension I built to change background color only changes the color of the body of the popup.html how to fix this

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Color Change</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button id="colorBtn" class ="redbutton" style="height: 50px; width: 75px;" >Change Color</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
//popup.js

const color = "#ff8346"; //red




document.getElementById("colorBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    changeBackgroundColor(color);
});

function changeBackground(color) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: {tabId: tabs[0].id},
            function: changeBackgroundColor,
            args: [color]
        });
    });
}

function changeBackgroundColor(color) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name":"color change",
    "version":"1.0",
    "permissions": ["scripting","activeTab"],
    "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
    
}
```

i was trying to get the button to trigger the function to change the body of the web page to change the color to red or any color but only the body of the popup.html changes color and not the web page

Comment: Remove `Color` in your click listener to call the correct function.

Comment: I have removed the color from the click function but now it seems to do nothing and I get no errors either

Comment: Not `color` but `Color`. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.